# How to synchronize transactions with Spring Tx?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-kafka, spring-data-mongodb, spring-transactions

I have three different sources to which I want to send information:

1. An Oracle database, related to a JpaRepository.
2. A MongoDB, related to a MongoRepository.
3. And a Kafka topic, which has configured via yml all the necessary data for producing into that topic.

I want to synchronize these resources with Spring Tx. I have a JpaTransactionManager related to the Oracle db, another MongoTransactionManager related to the MongoDB, and the KafkaTransactionManager created by Spring automatically when the transactions are activated.

The idea I had in mind was the following one:

1. First, I would have a basic controller that would autowire a service:

```
@RestController
public class SimpleController {

  @Autowired
  private SimpleService simpleService;

  @PostMapping(...)
  public Response doTx () {
    simpleService.doTx();
}
```

2. Then, that service would autowire at the same time another three services, one for each resource I have:

```
@Service
public class SimpleService {

  @Autowired
  private OracleService oracleService;

  @Autowired
  private MongoService mongoService;

  @Autowired
  private KafkaService kafkaService;
  
  ...
}
```

3. Such SimpleService, would have a method anotated with the @Transactional annotation in which these services are called:

```
@Service
public class SimpleService {

  @Transactional
  public void doTx () {

    oracleService.doTx();
    mongoService.doTx();
    kafkaService.doTx();

  }

}
```

4. And, each of these calls to these methods would be annotated with the @Transactional annotation too:

```
public class OracleService {

  @Autowired
  JpaRepository jpaRepository

  @Transactional
  public void doTx(){
    jpaRepository.save();
  }
}
```

What I would hope of this, is to initiate a transaction in SimpleService, and each of the other services that I call, join such transaction, and commit one after the other just when the method is about to return, at the end.

But this doesn't work. The only way it "works" (and I say "works" because it doesn't allow me to fully customize the order of committing the resources) is having all the resources in one service, all called from the same method:

```
@Service
public class SimpleService {

  @Autowired
  private JpaRepository oracleJpaRepository;

  @Autowired
  private MongoRepository mongoRepository;

  @Autowired
  private KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate;

  @Transactional(transactionManager = "oracleJpaTransactionManager")
  public void doTx() {
    oracleJpaRepository.save();
    mongoRepository.save();
    kafkaTemplate.send();

  }
```

So the questions is, basically, if my first approach a valid approach (which I think it is since it appears at some Spring Kafka code samples included in the documentation) and how to make it work (without the `ChainTransactionManager` which is deprecated).

All help is appreciated :D!

I tried to synchronize transactions with the above approach, but it would just commit whenever the method was called, not joining the previous transaction.

EDIT: I'm not trying to achieve full transactionality. Just synchronization, a Best Effort 1 Phase Commit. I know there may be some data inconsistency when synchronizing these resources, compensation is not a problem, the key is the chaining of the commits at the end of the method.

EDIT 2:

Following Spring Kafka Documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#ex-jdbc-sync

```
@Transactional("dstm")
public void someMethod(String in) {
    this.jdbcTemplate.execute("insert into mytable (data) values ('" + in + "')");
    sendToKafka(in);
}

@Transactional("kafkaTransactionManager")
public void sendToKafka(String in) {
    this.kafkaTemplate.send("topic2", in.toUpperCase());
}
```

The following example shows how transactions are nested, and they do synchronize.

Comment: You will always end up with multiple transactions, simply because you have multiple transactional resources. If the kafka send fails there is no way to rollback the OracleDB or MongoDB one as that has already committed. You only have the illussion of 1 transaction, which you don't really have. If you really want 1 tx you need something like JTA which allowsto span multiple resources, but this can be cumbersome to setup.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve here is to commit at the end of the method one after the other. I know it's not "fully transactional" meaning that if one commit fails the others won't roll back or automatically compensate. I'm just trying to "chain" all the commits together at the end of the method, so I get the Best Effort 1 phase commit. Compensation can be made afterwards. The key is the sync of the commits here :D!

Comment: You need multiple `@Transactional` annotations one for each resource on the service method. Or just create your own `ChainedTransactionManager` which simply loops over all tx managers to start/commit/rollback the transaction.

Comment: Is that first option of multiple @Transactional annotations documented somewhere over Spring? Could be helpful

Comment: No, but that is the most logical way to do it however it will explode your annotations, so the easiest is to simply write a `ChainedTransactionManager` yourself. It got deprecated because people assumed it was a proper and full blown implmentation and would do the correct things (which was never stated in the documentation). So if you are fine with the limitations you have with that, just copy the code and use your own implementation.

Comment: As stated on the github issue you created as well, your understanding on how `@Transactional` works is wrong. If it worked like you think it works there would have been no need for the `ChainedTransactionManager`. As I also commented here **and** the github issue is you would need multiple `@Transactional` annotations on the `SimpleService` method to achieve more or less the same as with the `ChainedTransactionManager`.

Comment: But since the ChainedTransactionManager is deprecated, does that mean that Spring no longer supports Transaction Synchronization with multiple Transaction Managers?

Because either it works as I am stating there, nesting multiple transactions into the outer transaction (with the \@Transactional in SimpleService calling to the other 3 services with the \@Transactional annotated methods) or Spring currently supports Transaction Synchronization with a deprecated Transaction Manager.

Comment: Please read my comments **and** the reason why the `ChainedTransactionManager` got deprecated in the first place. As I stated it doesn't work as you state and it never has worked like that, as there is no transaction syncronization **unless** you do that manually as it always has been. The `ChainedTransactionManager` was added to make this easier but due to the expectations of people for it to be a full blown transaction sync this support has been dropped so you need to do it yourself now. Which I stated over and over.

Comment: Moreover, having three methods annotated with the \@Transactional annotation called separately without an outer \@Transactional annotated method would mean that each transaction runs separately, not synchronizing between them.

And this example in Spring actually shows how nested transactional annotated methods should work, which does not work when more transaction managers/resources are added.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#ex-jdbc-sync

I'll edit the question to add the code snippet from the Spring Doc that says it works.

Comment: It doesn't work and works with 2 resource **only** partly and there is no syncronization as well. It will just commit the inner transaction and then the outer one. So adding an another transactional resource basically explodes this as there are now 3 transaction to syncronize, which will never happen. Basically your expectation is the (partial) reason why the `ChainedTransactionManager` got deprecated in the first place.

Comment: So you're telling me that the example Spring provides *does not synchronize* when reverting the order of the commits. Should that not be stated in the docs to clear any possibility of misconception?

And when I stated in the question that *I did achieve transactional synchronization* with the JpaTransactionManager as TransactionManager and all three resources commits *at the end of the Transaction*, you're telling me that Spring did not plan for it to work like that and what I achieve is just collateral and not documented anywhere?

I mean, forgive me but this sounds crazy.

Comment: What I expect of this functionality is to commit at the end of the method. I'm not expecting it to roll back already committed transactions, but I do expect it to put all resources together and do the commits one after the other in rapid fashion, not just following the service logic, which will cause a bigger span of time for the data inconsistency.

And like I said, it worked with the example above, all three resources waits till the end of the method.

Comment: They will commit but individually. If one fails/throws exception the remain will be rolled back. But that will only happen if you put 3 `@Transactional` annotation on your `SimpleService` method **not** if you individually annotate the seperate services. Also the syncronization you mention for Kafka is only because that is part of the Spring Kafka project and has explicitly been built in. But it only works for 1 other transactional resource.

Comment: Can you please post an answer to the question with a pseudo code of that? Because I think I'm following you but I'm not certain.

Comment: Duplicate annotation of non-repeatable type \@Transactional. Only annotation types marked \@Repeatable can be used multiple times at one target.

This is what I get when I try to annotate a method with three \@Transactional annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in short terms, **transactional synchronization with more than one database and kafka doesn't work**.

Transactional synchronization at its full capacity looks like it will only work with a deprecated Spring Transaction class, `ChainedTransactionManager`, which does synchronize at the end of the method all operations made with Transaction Managers specified in such `ChainedTransactionManager`.

Nested calls to Transactional annotated methods **won't synchronize**.

Databases and Kafka will only be synchronized if *only one database is put together with Kafka*, as the comments to the question states it will break once a second database enters the game.

You can either use another pattern (Transactional Outbox sounds solid for these cases, but it comes with a higher temporal frame of data inconsistency), or copypaste the ChainedTransactionManager class into your libraries/sample and play with it.

Note that the compensation once a commit fails will have to be done *manually*, since this is not XA or similar. So if you synchronize multiple databases and kafka, be sure to catch the Heuristic exceptions and compensate properly.

If you understand the drawbacks of using the `ChainedTransactionManager` it's an excellent tool to obtain such synchronization when your application needs to commit all resources together without business logic in between. Don't expect a Two-phase commit, this is a Best Effort 1 phase commit. So when a commit fails, all the commits made earlier **won't roll back, you have to compensate manually**.